# Get selected value in dropdown list and insert into database using asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist:

```
"SELECT name + ' (' + code + ')' AS Expr1 FROM Customer"
```

Then click `Save` and the dropdownlist selected item data insert into database.
but I just want to insert 'code' only
Can anyone help..Thanks

Comment: care to improve the question by adding more information about the requirement and what you have done already. And the supplied query doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
connection.Open()
If (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open)) Then
 cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (Column_name) VALUES ('" & DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value & "')", connection)
 Dim ra As Integer = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

you need to include the following snippet inside the Save button's click event